# What is the node pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

In a book i recently read, the author presented the 'node pattern' which looks close to EAV, but i couldn't find any useful and concrete informations about it.

Do you know any good document to point me to ? or explain what's it exactly ?

Comment: The book in question is probably `Pro Zend Framework Techniques: Build a Full CMS Project` by Forrest Lyman Apress 2009.  The author suggests this name for a variation on the Entity-Attribute-Value model.

Comment: In fact the note refering to EAV pattern tells '*You may notice that the node pattern, as I refer to it, is very similar to the EAV database pattern. The one
difference is the fact that the node pattern uses concrete tables, which can improve performance.*' And i would have like to know more about this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through a couple of pages, I realised node pattern is not a pattern on its own, its an adaptation of Entity-attribute-value pattern (EAV) for CMSs. You can find out more about the EAV pattern at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model . Hope thats helpfull

Answer (score 1):

it is a pattern , a database pattern , a way to abstract content types from te content itself .In a MVC application,  instead of defining a content type with a db table ( ie an article with a title and a content ) , the content type is abstract and defined in the model of your application. so your database only holds  content nodes  without a structure , and you use reflection in order to get the nodes linked to a content type in the model of your application.
Drupal cms uses this pattern too , so you can create content types within your app without create a new db table for the new type ( check cck in drupal ).
so you'll get a very simple db table but your model will be more complicated , but you'll be able to add new content types in you app just by creating a new class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such pattern. Design pattern is, by definition, something precisely defined and widely encountered - an observation, not an idea.

If it's not explained in the book and hard to find elsewhere - it's not a pattern.